# How to get all the rows which contain data in a particular column in Excel from C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have a data set in Excel and am using C# to open the worksheet and access some of the data.

I am trying to get all the rows that contain data from a particular column. For example in column `B` starting from cell 'B3' going down I want to store all the rows that contain data in a collection like an Array.

This is what I have so far:

```
Application excelApplication;
_Workbook workbook;
_Worksheet sheet;

excelApplication = new Excel.Application
  {
    Visible = true,
    ScreenUpdating = true
  };

workbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Documents and Settings\user\Desktop\Book1.xls");
sheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[2];

Excel.Range range = sheet.Range["b3:b145"].

foreach (Range cell in range)
   {

      // Do something with rows which contain data          
   }
```

As you can see above I have specified the range from B3 to B45 which I don't want. I want to get all the rows in the B column which contain data starting from B3.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

In general when I get stuck in these situations I record a Macro and convert the VBA code to C#. The object model in VSTO is pretty much exactly the same (remember this its a great tip) and with .Net 4.0 onwards optional parameters save a lot of code.

In your particular instance I envisage the larger the spreadsheet the longer it will take to read all the Excel cells in column B using VSTO. My advice is to use this technique to read them all at once:

```
//Work out the number of rows with data in column B:
//int lastColumn = range.Columns.Count;
int lastRow = range.Rows.Count;

//Get all the column values:
object[,] objectArray = shtName.get_Range("B3:B" + lastRow.ToString()).Value2;
rngName.Value2 = objectArray;
```

Comment: But what do I set the `range` object to? in my code I had `range = sheet.Range["b3:b145"];` but I don't want to specify the range myself I want to work out in c# which cells have data in the B column

Comment: Set the `range` to column B, eg `range = sheet.Range["B3"];` then check the Rows.Count. In your for-loop skip `IsNullOrEmpty` cells. I am not sure if you want gaps in the sequence (of B column cells) preserved or not.

Comment: The Rows.Count returns 1 if I set the range to `range = sheet.Range["b3"];`

Comment: Ok then set it to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = sheet.UsedRange;` - **Edit** I am on a mac let me jump on my PC to find better code.

Comment: The thing with `UsedRange` is that it includes any cell that has ever been used, so if I add data to a cell and then delete it afterwards it will still include that cell in the count. That's not what I want

Comment: If you do delete cell/values and they are interfering with the usedRange make sure you clean them up properly. I use [VSTOContrib](http://jake.ginnivan.net/vsto-contrib/introduction) for this purpose. Otherwise its probably easier to populate temporary cell values in another Sheet with a VeryHidden visibility. Another alternative is using the xlEnd direction selection methods (eg same as Ctrl+DownKey) as shown [here](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/12/06/find-last-used-cell-excel/), although that wont work if there is gaps in the column sequence of data.